# I need to return a link generated after the completion of ModelForm

Tags: python, django

part of forms.py

class FormPublicar(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Publicacao
    exclude = ('usuario', 'aprovado', 'cadastrado_em', 'slug')

def enviar(self):
    titulo = 'mensagem enviada pelo site'
    destino = self.cleaned_data['emailp']
    mensagem = u"""
    Message that will be sent after completing the form.
    Here I must pass a link to the full URL into the body of the email, something like:
    [ 1 ]http://www.domain.com/item/playstation3/
                         /view/slug/   
    """  % self.cleaned_data

    send_mail(
        subject = titulo,
        message = mensagem,
        from_email = 'inform@domain.com',
        recipient_list =[destino],
        )
```

[ 1 ] I read about the "reverse", tried to mount url + view + parameter.
But I could not generate the link correctly, did a number of ways but could not.

I need to pass the domain name+view+parameter slug that is generated after completing the form.

For the recipient of e-mail see the correct link.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reverse()` is normally the proper way to generate the portion of the URL without the domain. For example, if your URL config contains something like the following:

```
(r'^item/(?P<item>[-%\w]+)/view/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', 'my_view_function')
```

Then the following call

```
reverse('my_view_function', kwargs={'item': 'playstation3', 'slug': 'my-slug'})
```

should return `/item/playstation3/view/my-slug`.

Preferably, your model `Publicacao` should define a `get_absolute_url` method that returns the actual URL for the model instance. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url.

The domain name part could be retrieved using the Sites framework:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> s = Site.objects.get_current()
>>> s.domain
u'localhost:8000'
```

Of course, you will have to configure the domain of your site properly. See also http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls.

Answer (score 0):

Bernd, thanks.
About the "reverse" I already knew.

A short example.
here is only a matter of identation.  http://pastebin.ca/1977489

Thanks and I apologize, I'm still studying Django.

Comment: Can you show the URL configuration of the view function that should be called when the recipient of that email clicks on the link you want to include in the message body?